# Why K8S statefulsets volumeClaimTemplates status is pending , but the pod, pvc, pv are all fine?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I use nfs-subdir-external-provisioner as automatic pv provisioner for my promethues (by promethues-operator )
I have created our sts,pod,pvc,pv successfully and everything looks fine.
But if I use kubectl get sts -o yaml , the status is still  "phase: Pending"....
Anyone have idea about it ?

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: prometheus-k8s-db
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: managed-nfs-storage
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending
```

```
NAME             READY   AGE
prometheus-k8s   2/2     26m
```

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
prometheus-k8s-0                       2/2     Running   0          28m
prometheus-k8s-1                       2/2     Running   0          28m
```

```
NAME                                 STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS          AGE
prometheus-k8s-db-prometheus-k8s-0   Bound    pvc-77c8035e-fe32-4c0d-8302-930b39979fc1   5Gi        RWO            managed-nfs-storage   3h57m
prometheus-k8s-db-prometheus-k8s-1   Bound    pvc-21989d64-cc89-4aed-bed5-30bd22c0ae35   5Gi        RWO            managed-nfs-storage   3h57m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause it's part of the `spec` field. It does not reflect any real status, just provides an information on how should a new pvc be created. This will not transition to any other state, ever.

Comment: So it looks like a normal status?  thanks for your answer :)